# Can't play video in VideoView - why?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am trying to play a video in VideoView in android but it always gives ( 1 -2147483648 ) error.

At first, I tried to play from URL, it didn't work so I downloaded the video, saved it on the raw folder and tried to play but it is still not working.
when I googled the error ( 1 -2147483648 ), it says that this error occurs due to issues like incorrect URL or incompatible format but the video is .mp4 with the H264 codec.
What else should I consider in order to play the video?

//activity

video_view.setMediaController(MediaController(context))

```
    val videoPath="android.resource://" + context!!.packageName+ "/" + R.raw.howappvideo
    video_view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoPath))
    video_view.requestFocus()
    video_view.setOnPreparedListener {
        Log.i("SeeAllFragment","video is prepared")
        try{
            video_view.start()
        }catch (e:Exception){
            Log.i("SeeAllFragment","error while playing ${e.printStackTrace()}")
        }
    }
    video_view.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
        toast("video completed")
        mp!!.release()
    }
    video_view.setOnErrorListener { mp, what, extra ->
        Log.i("SeeAllFragment","error while loading video $what $extra ")
        true
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it says that this error occurs due to issues like incorrect URL or
>   incompatible format but the video is .mp4 with the H264 codec.

=> Reason being is `VideoView` is not that much powerful and extensible, in terms of codecs and other features.

Rather I would suggest going with [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) library.

There are multiple things why `VideoView` is failed to play video, one of the reasons being is when you record using other devices like iPhone, Camcorder, etc. They have a different format of video which might not be supported, also codec might not be supported. In this case, when we are developing solutions and having android/iPhone/TV or other mediums involved, we implement a code over backend for maintaining a single codec and that's how we maintain the compatibility with all the devices.

Comment: If possible can you share video?

Comment: Actually ya..in this application that I'm working we get a URL from the server...the video is playing fine on iPhone, it just has this issue with android..so you mean to say that there might be some issues in the backend??

Comment: Yeah we need to convert videos that we receive from android or iPhone and maintain the same codec which works in both.

Comment: ok, but when I checked the video's properties it says that the video is in mp4 format with h264 codec...isn't it enough to play the video??

Comment: @RubynaThapa H264 codec is fine but there are different profiles like Baseline Profile (BP), Main Profile (MP), etc. Read this thread https://superuser.com/questions/489087/what-are-the-differences-between-h-264-profiles

Comment: okay, now I understand...Thank you so much for your quick response...It was really helpful

Comment: @RubynaThapa Glad, it has found helpful. However, I would suggest please share your findings what you found and implemented exactly to sort out this issue.